# Keep getting error status on Kubernetes Cron Job with connection refused?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

I am trying to write a cron job which hits a rest endpoint of the application it is pulling image of.
Below is the sample code:

```
---
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: {{ .Chart.Name }}-cronjob
  labels:
    app: {{ .Release.Name }}
    chart: {{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
spec:
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 2
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 2
  startingDeadlineSeconds: 1800
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          name: {{ .Chart.Name }}-cronjob
          labels:
            app: {{ .Chart.Name }}
        spec:
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
          containers:
            - name: demo
              image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
              command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "curl http://localhost:8080/hello"]
              readinessProbe:
                httpGet:
                  path: "/healthcheck"
                  port: 8081
                initialDelaySeconds: 300
                periodSeconds: 60
                timeoutSeconds: 30
                failureThreshold: 3
              livenessProbe:
                httpGet:
                  path: "/healthcheck"
                  port: 8081
                initialDelaySeconds: 300
                periodSeconds: 60
                timeoutSeconds: 30
                failureThreshold: 3
              resources:
                requests:
                  cpu: 200m
                  memory: 2Gi
                limits:
                  cpu: 1
                  memory: 6Gi
  schedule: "*/5 * * * *"
```

But i keep running into `*curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused*`.
I can see from the events that it creates the container and immediately throws: Back-off restarting failed container.
I already have pods running of demo app and it works fine, it is just when i am trying to point to this existing app and hit a rest endpoint i start running into connection refused errors.

Exact output when seeing the logs:

```
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused
```

Event Logs:

```
Container image "wayfair/demo:728ac13-as_test_cron_job" already present on machine
9m49s       Normal    Created                pod/demo-cronjob-1619108100-ndrnx   Created container demo
6m17s       Warning   BackOff                pod/demo-cronjob-1619108100-ndrnx   Back-off restarting failed container
5m38s       Normal    SuccessfulDelete       job/demo-cronjob-1619108100         Deleted pod: demo-cronjob-1619108100-ndrnx
5m38s       Warning   BackoffLimitExceeded   job/demo-cronjob-1619108100         Job has reached the specified backoff limit
```

Being new to K8, Any pointers are helpful!

Comment: why the readiness and liveness probes point to port 8081 and the curl to 8080, shouldn't the curl point to 8081?

Comment: The app setup is in a way that healthcheck points to 8081 & app runs on 8080 so the curl command needs to run against 8080

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to connect to `localhost:8080` with your curl which doesn't make sense from what I understand of your CronJob definition.

From the docs (at https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#define-a-command-and-arguments-when-you-create-a-pod )

> The **command** and **arguments** that you define in the configuration file
> **override** the default command and arguments provided by the container
> image. If you define args, but do not define a command, the default
> command is used with your new arguments.
>
> Note: The command field corresponds to entrypoint in some container
> runtimes. Refer to the Notes below.

If you define a command for the image, even if the image would start a rest application on port 8080 on localhost with its default entrypoint (or command, depends on the container type you are using), the command overrides the entrypoint and no application is start.

If you have the necessity of both starting the application and then performing other operations, like curls and so on, I suggest to use a `.sh` script or something like that, depending on what is the Job objective.

Comment: Thanks @AanD i was able to remove the overriding of commands and was able to bring the container up but i still want to hit a couple of rest endpoints of that application.

Can you suggest how to call this shell script which has a bunch of curls ? And also, wouldn't the order of execution be an issue here? Since i only want to run these commands after the app comes up.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that you should drop the web app process in the foreground, do a while to poll it (curl until 200 on an health endpoint maybe?) until it is ready, then make your curls, then close everything up. To run both, if you are using Docker, check the official docs ( https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/ ). Another option is to keep the REST app always up and running in its own Deployment, then have the CronJob only start the bash script making the various curls. Or have the CronJob start 2 containers.